# How to restore mysql from backup?

Tags: php, mysql

I have got alldatabase.sql file
How I can restore data with it?

My console comand is not working:

```
mysqldump -u root -p < alldatabase.sql
```

I must to create database first, but all database in my one file. What I must to do?

Comment: Have you read the documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use mysqldump to take a snapshot, but you restore using the mysql command

`mysql -u root -p < alldatabase.sql`

Comment: thanks a lot! How I can create new user in console with all privilegies to one of database?

Comment: Great that your problem is solved. Please consider accepting the answer (if the timer is expired) and then ask another question for your new problem. Please do a search in between, I'm sure that question was already answered here.